# ¿Cuál sería una palabra general para archivos tar, zip, 7zip, etc.?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática

En ingles existe "archiver" (como en "file archiver") pero en español "archivador" significa:

> 1. adj. Que archiva. U. t. c. s.
> 2. m. Mueble de oficina convenientemente dispuesto para archivar documentos, fichas u otros papeles.
> 3. m. Carpeta convenientemente dispuesta para archivar documentos, fichas u otros papeles.

-[RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3SkGR1g)

Y "archivar" significa:

> 1. tr. Guardar documentos o información en un archivo.
>      [...]

-[RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3SlWS8T%7C3SrKnVZ)

Por lo que "archivo archivador" es redundante, y "archivador" es demasiado abarcativo (incluye cualquier cosa que guarde información).

¿Cuál sería una palabra general para archivos tar, zip, 7zip, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aunque no está recogido en el DRAE, se suele usar el término "archivos **comprimidos**" o a veces "archivos **empaquetados**".

> En ciencias de la computación, la compresión de datos es la reducción del volumen de datos tratables para representar una determinada información empleando una menor cantidad de espacio. Al acto de compresión de datos se denomina «**compresión**», y al contrario «descompresión».
>
> fuente: [Compresión de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compresi%C3%B3n_de_datos)

El término se usa independientemente del algoritmo usado para comprimir la información.

> Un archivo **comprimido**, es el resultado de tratar un archivo, documento, carpeta, etc., con un programa específico para comprimir, cuyo objetivo principal es reducir su peso para que ocupe menos espacio, pero con este proceso no perdemos la información original.
>
> fuente: [Básico y fácil](https://basicoyfacil.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/que-es-un-archivo-comprimido/)

No sé si hay algún método que archive sin comprimir, pero en cualquier caso se le daría el nombre que se ha dado a los otros archivos codificados (comprimidos) por los otros métodos que sí usan algoritmos que comprimen la información. Yo he oído "comprimidos" mucho más que "empaquetados".

Comment: tar no es comprimido, solo es un "reordenamiento" de la información. "El programa tar, es usado para almacenar archivos y directorios en un solo archivo, no para comprimirlos." fuente [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar#El_programa).

Comment: Creo que para generalizar, incluyendo a tar, "empaquetados" sería más correcto. Lo que no se es si es inteligible.

Comment: @Diego Sí, Rar y Zip (estoy casi seguro que la mayoría también), poseen métodos para archivar (se llama precisamente "solo archivar") sin comprimir. Archivos comprimidos es lo que dices, archivar es justamente crear el rar o zip sin comprimir.

Comment: @Billeeb Pero el sustantivo es lo que busco, no el verbo.

Comment: No dice eso en tu pregunta: ¿Cuál sería una palabra general para archivos tar, zip, 7zip, etc.? **Archivos comprimidos**.
Mi frase **archivar** se refería a la pregunta que decía si existían archivos sin comprimir (en formato rar u otro). La función que uno usa para crearlos es **archivar** en vez de **comprimir**. Así que vendrían a ser "archivo en formato rar sin comprimir", por ejemplo. A diferencia de "archivo comprimido". Ese es el sustantivo (sustantivo+adjetivo como objeto).

Comment: @Billeeb seguro que lo sabes, pero para dirigirte a Emmanuel debes usar `@EmmanuelMess`. Si no, no recibirá notificación de tu mensaje.

Comment: @emmanuelmess respuesta arriba.

Comment: @Billeeb tar es un formato que no comprime, hice la pregunta para poder encontrar una palabra que lo incluyera con otros formatos que si comprimen. Debí haberlo especificado.

Comment: @emmanuelmess Archivo tar. Así se llama. Es un archivo que funciona como contenedor de otro. Es lo mismo que pasa con el avi y el mkv. Le estás dando vueltas de más a algo sin sentido. Cuál es la diferencia entre un archivo de texto y un word, si ambos muestran texto?? Rtf? Md, json? Php? Si sirven para cosas distintas no los puedes agrupar en el mismo grupo. Seguro si googleas por un tar, te definirá qué tipo de nombre tiene un wrapper. Ya respondí lo que tiene sentido y es relevante. Usa wikipedia o googlea. Si necesitas, pregunta qué es un archivo y comienza de ahí.

Comment: @emmanuelmess revisa la historia del desarrollo de dichos archivos, ahí te dará una lógica de por qué se incluye en los lectores de archivos comprimidos, aunque técnicamente no tiene compresión alguna. Es lo mismo que un archivo txt. Por qué lo abre el word si no tiene formato ni es posible dárselo? Si respondes eso, tienes la respuesta al problema del tar.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess Lee esto: "The Unix tools ar, tar, cpio act as archivers but not compressors. Users of the Unix tools use additional compression tools, such as gzip, bzip2, or xz, to compress the archive file after packing or remove compression before unpacking the archive file. The filename extensions are successively added at each step of this process. For example, archiving a collection of files with tar and then compressing the resulting archive file with gzip results a file with .tar.gz extension." EL archivo de extensión **.tar** es un "archivo archivador", un "archivo comprimido" es ídem.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess El archivo tar y otros por le estilo creados en los inicios de Unix no son lo mismo que zip, rar u otros con compresión. El caso de tar responde a Unix y su filosofía de que un programa debía hacer una sola cosa lo mejor posible y nada más. Tar sólo junta archivos (más info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing) ). La mayoría de los archivos tar se distribuyen como tar.gzip que es la compresión posterior. En Windows/DOS, los progs ejecutan ambas tareas: comprimen y ofrecen "solo archivar" como un método opcional (haciendo dos cosas al mismo tiempo a diferencia de unix).

Comment: @EmmanuelMess Como antecesor de todos los archivos "archivadores" o "empaquetadores", tar es legible por casi todos los programas de compresión, sin embargo, no es un archivo "comprimido". Desde ese punto de vista, deberías llamar al conjunto que hiciste (tar, rar, zip, ar, cpio, etc.) como "archivos empaquetados" (MKV cae dentro de ese mismo grupo). Si hablas de los "comprimidos" (rar, zip, arj, gzip, targzip, etc.) entonces son "archivos comprimidos".

Answer (score 1):

Por dar una alternativa, se usa también el término ***volumen*** (entendido como "volumen de información" o "de datos").

La RAE define *[volumen](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c2Xhjoi)* como:

> 3. m. Cuerpo material de un libro encuadernado, ya contenga la obra completa, o uno o más tomos de ella, o ya lo constituyan dos o más escritos diferentes.

Por analogía con los *volúmenes* de una obra impresa, cuando los archivos ZIP o RAR tenían que comprimirse en varios archivos para que cupieran en disquetes se les llamaba así. De hecho, el término se puede encontrar en la web:

> *Para comprimir un archivo en varias partes solo tiene que especificar el tamaño que desea que tenga cada parte en la opción **Partir en volúmenes** de la ventana de compresión.* ([Fuente.](http://www.winrar.es/soporte/articulo/41?query=volumenes&PHPSESSID=0hbk735rmpg97mvic1287g95hl43kb7c))
>
> *Los archivos RAR constan de dos partes: el volumen de datos (RAR) y el volumen de recuperación (REV).* ([Fuente.](https://www.online-convert.com/es/formato-de-archivo/rar))

En todo caso, este término se usaba más cuando había que separar los archivos comprimidos en varios *volúmenes*, cosa que hoy día ha perdido casi todo el sentido.